# How to go from a list of points to an object

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, 3ds

I am currently writing a c++ program that generates brillouin zones(If you don't know what they are that is fine). The output is a list of points defined by they're x, y, and z coordinates. I would like to turn that list of points into a solid object in either an .stl or a .3ds. If it is possible I would like to have the c++ program do the 3d file creation, because the point list files are several gigs when you write them to txt so you can't load the list into ram as one piece without crashing the computer. Does anyone have an Idea how to do that?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make a "mesh" from a "point cloud."  You may find "mesh" and "point cloud" to be useful search terms.

Comment: You will need to tessellate (like triangulation but in 3D) the points. After doing so, you an easily write an STL file (as it is just a collection of triangles). To tessellate the point cloud, you can use libraries like [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) or some other programs like [voro++](http://math.lbl.gov/voro++/about.html)

Answer (score 1):

The STL format is simply a list of triangles defined by their coordinates. If you have already generated the triangles, writing STL is pretty much a matter of simply listing triplets of (x,y,z) values.

STL can be written in ASCII or binary. If you haven't looked inside an ASCII STL file, do so. Let me know if you would like a sample.

You can write the file one triangle at a time.

Comment: The problem is that I just have the points. The program has no way of knowing which to connect to which in a triangle.

Comment: It is not at all clear that there is a deterministic way to do it. If you have a guaranteed convex shape, it is doable, but if it is not convex then there are likely to be multiple ways to connect points into a surface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known file format of .3ds or .stl but I'm assuming that could be generated by blocks (write n points, update with other points, etc...).

My idea will be:
-Read the file by blocks (ex: line)
-process the points
-save that block
-continue with next.

Is possible that is needed to save dummy data (ex: if the file format .3ds have a header with info about the total count of points contained in the file, in this case put 0, when processing count the points and latter save the correct value).

Comment: It is not at all clear that there is a deterministic way to do it. If you have a guaranteed convex shape, it is doable, but if it is not convex then there are likely to be multiple ways to connect points into a surface.